# Extremely large query giving performance issues

Tags: sql, performance, oracle10g

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1
WHERE COLUMN1='x1'
AND COLUMN2  ='Y1'
AND COLUMN3  = 'Z1'
AND COLUMN4  ='N1'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1
WHERE COLUMN1='x1'
AND COLUMN2  ='Y1'
AND COLUMN3  = 'Z1'
AND COLUMN4  ='N2' 
UNION ALL...
```

The values are as follows :

X1 Y1 Z1 N1 : X1 Y1 Z1 N2 : ....

then,

X1 Y1 Z2 N1 : X1 Y1 Z2 N2 : ....

then

X1 Y2 Z1 N1 : X1 Y2 Z2 N2 : ....

then

X2 Y1 Z1 N1 :.... and the whole process repeats.

FORMS 100 TO 200 UNION ALLS.
All I need to do is to check whether the combination(COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4) exists in the table (Count would return 0 if it does not exist).

I know that this is a really bad way of writing queries, but I am a newbie. So please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `WHERE` clause to handle the common parts.  Then use a `CASE` statement buried in a `SUM` statement for the `column4` portion:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN COLUMN4 = 'N1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS N1Count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN COLUMN4 = 'N2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS N2Count
FROM TABLE1
WHERE COLUMN1 = 'x1'
  AND COLUMN2 = 'Y1'
  AND COLUMN3 = 'Z1'
```

This would prevent the running of all those separate `SELECT` statements.

Making sure you have indexes on `COLUMN1`, `COLUMN2`, `COLUMN3`, and `COLUMN4` would also help.

**EDIT 1:**

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN
    COLUMN1 = 'X1' AND COLUMN2 = 'Y1' AND COLUMN3 = 'Z1' AND COLUMN4 = 'N1'
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN
    COLUMN1 = 'X1' AND COLUMN2 = 'Y1' AND COLUMN3 = 'Z1' AND COLUMN4 = 'N2'
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN
    COLUMN1 = 'X1' AND COLUMN2 = 'Y2' AND COLUMN3 = 'Z1' AND COLUMN4 = 'N1'
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN
    COLUMN1 = 'X1' AND COLUMN2 = 'Y2' AND COLUMN3 = 'Z2' AND COLUMN4 = 'N2'
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count4,
  SUM(CASE WHEN
    COLUMN1 = 'X2' AND COLUMN2 = 'Y1' AND COLUMN3 = 'Z1' AND COLUMN4 = 'N1'
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count5,
  AND ETC.....
FROM TABLE1
```

**EDIT 2:**

You could create another table that holds all of the different variations of `COLUMN1`, `COLUMN2`, `COLUMN3`, and `COLUMN4`.  Then `JOIN` to that table and use `GROUP BY` like so:

```
SELECT tt.COLUMN1, tt.COLUMN2, tt.COLUMN3, tt.COLUMN4, 
  CASE WHEN t1.COLUMN1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(1) END AS RecCount
FROM TABLE1 t1
  RIGHT JOIN TempTable tt ON tt.COLUMN1 = t1.COLUMN1, tt.COLUMN2 = t1.COLUMN2, 
                             tt.COLUMN3 = t1.COLUMN3, tt.COLUMN4 = t1.COLUMN4
GROUP BY tt.COLUMN1, tt.COLUMN2, tt.COLUMN3, tt.COLUMN4
```

Comment: **@Leocode**, well you have completely changed the complexity of your query.  I have edited my answer showing how to accomplish what you want.

Comment: The query you are providing will return me thousands of columns since the records in the table are really high. Thanks.

Comment: **@Leocode**, isn't that what you want?  It should run faster as well, right?

Comment: I could use it if they are rows. If number of columns that can be used in ORACLE is limited(1000 I think). :)

Comment: **@Leocode**, I edited my answer again to give you another option.

Answer (score 0):

Why so many `UNION ALL` statements? I see only `column4` values changing in the predicate.

Try `WHERE EXISTS` for column4. And make sure you have required index for the columns listed in the `where` clause. Take care of the `leading column` in the index.

Usually, developers write a `IN list` for all the values to be compared. But, it is not efficient since the `table` will be scanned for each value in the IN list.

Also, if you don't have frequent `DML` changes for first three columns, then create a `PARTITION` to store those values in that partition.

And, **with any performance tuning question, always provide the execution plan and the metadata information.** It helps us to understand your issue better.

Comment: Ok, I see your modified question. Now you have two columns with varying values, which means two columns in the predicate of the query with multiple conditions for the varying values. So, as I suggested in my answer, now include the other column as well.

Comment: Actually all 4 columns vary.

Comment: So what? Use the same suggestion for all the columns. What stops you from at least trying? If you find any difficulty, I would be happy to help you. But, first try and let me know.